# Convert to JSON with Gson

Tags: scala, gson

I have the following structure in Scala:

```
Iterator[Seq[MyObject]]
```

What I want is to convert this object into seq of JSONArrays. Here's my code:

```
myobjects.foreach(it => Seq(gson.toJson(it)))
```

Unfortunately, instead of:

```
[{myObj}, {myObj}, {myObj}]
[{myObj}, {myObj}, {myObj}]
[{myObj}, {myObj}, {myObj}]
```

I'm getting:

```
{"head": {myObj}, "tl": {}}{"head": {myObj}, "tl": {}}{"head": {myObj}, "tl": {}}
{"head": {myObj}, "tl": {}}{"head": {myObj}, "tl": {}}{"head": {myObj}, "tl": {}}
{"head": {myObj}, "tl": {}}{"head": {myObj}, "tl": {}}{"head": {myObj}, "tl": {}}
```

How to convert my data structure into the json I want?

Comment: Using a **Scala** library that understands **Scala** types instead of using a reflection-based **Java** library.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I'm limited by tools I can access on my offline workstation, I have gson and jackson only available.

Comment: I believe **Jackson** has a **Scala** module but then again you probably can't use it if it isn't in the limited set of libraries you can use. I really do not understand what is the point of using a language if you can't really use it, no language ever is useful without its ecosystem of libraries. - If you are stuck with a bunch of **Java** libraries I would guess **Kotlin** would be a better language, at the end of the day you probably wouldn't be using much of the advanced features of **Scala** in any case, so going with something that has better interop support with **Java** would be better

Comment: this is off-topic, but I've made good experiences with Circe for JSON encoders/decoders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it today, it requires using a converter, but the solution is quite simple:

```
myobjects.foreach(it => {
  val jsonList = seqAsJavaListConverter(it)
  gson.toJson(javaList.asJava))
})
```

Comment: You can call `asJava` directly on a **List**.